# Getting started photoshop design for an Android application

Tags: android, responsive-design, photoshop, android-drawable

I am designing an android application in photoshop. But I am stuck at the first step itself.
I have so many confusion and after searching for a solution in google confusion increased threefold.

My big confusions are

1.What should be the canvas size
2.What is the size of status bar
3.How many sizes of assets i have to handover to development team.

Few suggested me to do everything in DP. Again confusion.

1.How to setup photoshop workspace in DP.
2.What is the size of the canvas I have to start with.
3.What is the size of status bar.
4.how to set text size in sp.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't even try to say the word **PSD**, or I'll hot glue your hat with your head... ;) Joking of course. The question is a bit too broad. Have a look to [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: This might help you get started - http://grahamtodman.co.uk/blog/2013/02/how-to-design-android-apps-in-photoshop-what-the-frak-is-a-dp/

Comment: @JoelFernandes I did that. He says to start with 320*480 but what is the size status bar there. What is size of Action bar icons in that resolution.

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/index.html -- there are thousands of Android devices, and there is no set size for any of the UI elements. You will need to design your assets for the various resolution buckets.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo Frankly telling that link started my confusion. Every thing they say is using DP as a unit. How can I do that in photoshop.

Comment: @323go  All of you thinking i am an idiot because i am a new user to stackoverflow. Dont mind.. Just joking.. i have gone through all those pages of developer.android.com my dear friend. Frankly tell me.. can you answer above question by reading all those pages

Comment: Most of them, yes. Some don't have answers. Canvas size is different for devices, as is status bar. (I.3) is easy -- you just *need* one size, but ideally you'll have assets for the most used resolutions, usually mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi. (I.4) doesn't even apply to asset design.

Comment: @323go My confusion here is what is the size of MDPi device in pixel. Because to set canvas size I need size in pixels.

Comment: mdpi = 160dpi. Actual pixels depend on the screen size, which will differ between devices. A 7" mdpi device has a 6.1" x 3.43" screen and will be around 1024x600 (Galaxy Tab 2, for example). A 10.1" mdpi device has a 8.8" x 5" screen and would probably come in at 1280x800. Get your target devices (or emulators) and check the resolution and density. On a device, jotabout's ScreenInfo is a great (free) app for this.

Comment: **resolution != dimension**. dp is not a **real** measure unit. It's a **concept**. You still work in pixels (dimension), but taking dpi in account (resolution). So you have to make different sizes of your images, in **different resolutions**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider **dp = px** in Photoshop

1. **xlarge** screens are at least **960dp x 720dp**
2. **large** screens are at least **640dp x 480dp**
3. **normal** screens are at least **470dp x 320dp**
4. **small** screens are at least **426dp x 320dp**

Following more specific

1. **320dp**: *a typical phone screen* (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
2. **480dp**: *a tweener tablet like the Streak* (480x800 mdpi).
3. **600dp**: *a 7” tablet* (600x1024 mdpi).
4. **720dp**: *a 10” tablet* (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Download the Sample android PSD from [here](http://bit.ly/1eMu37O)

for more reference [click here](http://bit.ly/1cFACXL)

I hope it would help you

Comment: The links are marked as malicious. Could you please post direct links instead of shortened URLs?

Comment: @Aborted They are not malicious I just shortened it, you can proceed without any risk :)

Comment: I know but I cannot ignore the browser warning. It would be nice if you provided the direct links.

Comment: @Aborted http://kintek.com.au/blog/portkit-ux-metaphor-equivalents-for-ios-and-android/    and    https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html